# Generate random number in MIPS

Tags: random, mips

How can I generate random number in MIPs that similar to C Standard Library
this is the C code.
Please help me

```
uint32_t random_in_range(uint32_t low, uint32_t high)
{
  uint32_t range = high-low+1;
  uint32_t rand_num = get_random();

  return (rand_num % range) + low;
}


// Generate random 32-bit unsigned number
// based on multiply-with-carry method shown
// at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation

uint32_t get_random()
{
  uint32_t result;
  m_z = 36969 * (m_z & 65535) + (m_z >> 16);
  m_w = 18000 * (m_w & 65535) + (m_w >> 16);
  result = (m_z << 16) + m_w;  /* 32-bit result */
  return result;
}
```

Comment: So get a MIPS instruction set reference and translate this code line by line into MIPS assembly. Or use a C compiler to do it for you. It's not at all clear what the problem is.

Comment: You can just [have a compiler do the work](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fYZ6Mb). Compilers are good at that. That's their job.